# Conditional Count over Columns with average calculations over results

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with this structure

```
v1|v2|v3|
 2| 3| 4|
  | 5| 4|
 5| 1| 4|
```

I waht to count all 4's and 5's for each column and divide it by the number of all entries of that column. Afterwards I want to calculate the mean of all these values. In this case `(1/2+1/3+3/3)/3=0.611`

```
sum over x(Count Vx if 4 or 5)/Count Vx(without missings)/x
```

What I have tried so far is:
`df[df > 4 and df > 5].count(`) but I already get a lot of errors here. Anyone who can bring on on the right track?

Comment: df > 4 and df > 5 equal to df > 5 , also in pandas (df > 4)&(df > 5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.isin([4,5]).sum().div(df.count()).mean()
```

Output:

```
0.611111111111111
```