# Conditional count calculations groupwise

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am calculating the conditional count ([only 4's and 5's divided by all values over all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59214712/conditional-count-over-columns-with-average-calculations-over-results?noredirect=1#comment104645416_59214712)) of the following table

```
v1|v2|v3|
 2| 3| 4|
  | 5| 4|
 5| 1| 4|
```

with this `df.isin(\[4,5\]).sum().div(df.count()).mean()` . I thought it would be easy to apply this command grouped by an additional column like this

```
code|v1|v2|v3|
1234|2| 3| 4|
1234| | 5| 4|
1234|5| 1| 4|
2345|2|  | 4|
2345| | 5| 4|
2345|5| 1| 4|
```

to get one value for each `code` using this `df.isin(\[4,5\]).groupby().sum().div(df.count()).mean()` but instead I get some weird result like

```
code|
v1  |0.985
v2  |0.475
v3  |0.874
```

Instead of

```
code|
1234|0.611
2345|0.666
```

Could anyone help me to re-write or exend the command I have so I can get values for each `code`?

****************EDIT: Due to misunderstandings I add some more information

Code 1234 we have in

```
Column 1: one 4 or 5 and 2 values alltogether. = 1/2
Column 2: one 4 or 5 and 3 values alltogether = 1/3
Column 3: three 4 or 5 and 3 values alltogether = 3/3
```

Now we calculate the mean of this:= `(1/2+1/3+3/3)/3=0.61111`

This is for one code. I need this for all codes. In R I would say I split the table into one list for each code and calculate what I did above. I am wondering If I could do this by extending the line of code I got by my other question. Like using .groupby or so?

Comment: `df.isin([4, 5]).stack().mean(level=0)`, assuming that code is your index.

Comment: Then make it the index.

Comment: I don't understand why you are dividing by `df.count()`, or why you are summing, neither of those were in the code I posted.

Comment: Then I don't understand your output at all.  Please review [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Your output doesn't correspond to what your input and given calculation at all.  At the very least, since your data are identical between the groups, the output should be the same between the two groups.  Please clarify.

Comment: I'm still not sure about your intent.  In your original question you wanted a `sum (Count Vx in (4, 5) / Count Vx if not None)`, but it that gives you a totally different number.  Currently you're calculating the `(4 or 5)/Total` over the columns and then dividing by 3, but if you apply it over the entire section it'll be 5/8 and 5/7 respectively which doesn't match your output.  So which one is it?

Comment: I synchronized everything and added a detailed explanation. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using `groupby.apply` with `code` as index and then use the function provided in your answer.  It's not an optimal solution but it can achieve the specific way you wanted to add calculate the average:

Given a `DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
>>> df
   code    v1    v2 v3
0  1234     2     3  4
1  1234  None     5  4
2  1234     5     1  4
3  2345     2  None  4
4  2345  None     5  4
5  2345     5     1  4
```

Do this:

```
>>> df.set_index('code').groupby(level=0).apply(lambda d: d.isin((4, 5)).sum().div(d.count()).mean())
code
1234    0.611111
2345    0.666667
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. could you maybe briefly comment, why this is not the optimal way?

Comment: Whenever possible, you should always be using a vectorized function in `pandas` as looping over the frame or using `apply`/`applymap` are slow in comparison.  So while it definitely works, with a large enough dataset, you'll start to notice the performance difference between using `apply` vs a vectorized implementation.